# print out binary representation of c type in python

Tags: python, c

I have the following number in `C`/`C++`, for example, `0x0202020202ULL` and I'd like to print it out in binary form `1000000010000000100000001000000010`.

Could you please help?

Comment: I actually meant ULL.

Comment: I fail to see the relevance of C here. You can have `0x0202020202` in Python as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a combination of slicing(or `str.rstrip`), `int` and `format`.

```
>>> inp = '0x0202020202UL'
>>> format(int(inp[:-2], 16), 'b')
'1000000010000000100000001000000010'
# Using `str.rstrip`, This will work for any hex, not just UL
>>> format(int(inp.rstrip('UL'), 16), 'b')
'1000000010000000100000001000000010'
```

**Update:**

```
from itertools import islice
def formatted_bin(inp):
   output = format(int(inp.rstrip('UL'), 16), 'b')
   le = len(output)
   m = le % 4
   padd = 4 - m if m != 0 else 0
   output  = output.zfill(le + padd)
   it = iter(output)
   return ' '.join(''.join(islice(it, 4)) for _ in xrange((le+padd)/4))

print formatted_bin('0x0202020202UL')
print formatted_bin('0x10')
print formatted_bin('0x101010')
print formatted_bin('0xfff')
```

**output:**

```
0010 0000 0010 0000 0010 0000 0010 0000 0010
0001 0000
0001 0000 0001 0000 0001 0000
1111 1111 1111
```

Comment: nice. just a little trick, how to separate it into 4 bits separated by a space, like `10 0000 0010 0000 0010 0000 0010 0000 0010`?

Comment: still not correct. for example ·0x10· would produce wrong result

Comment: @Eugene Using the rstrip version I got `'0001 0000'` for `0x10`. The slicing version is for unsigned long only, while `rstrip` version will work for any hex.